# Reparametrization theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, arc-length

The reparametrization theorem says the following:

> If $α:I\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a regular curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then there exists a reparametrization $\beta$ of  $\alpha$ such that $β$ has unit speed.

My question is this:

If the curve is not regular, then is there no arc length parameterization?.
What I tried was to get the following example $t\mapsto (|t|t,t^2)$ for $t\in[-1,1]$ whose graph would approximate this:

[image]

It is understood that when reaching point $(0,0)$ the particle that follows this route stops instantly and then he continues its journey, but if there were a parameterization $\beta$ by arc length, it means that when reaching that point it would continue with $||\beta'||=1$, is there such a possibility? How would it be explained if it existed.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of reparametrization and arc-length parametrization ? Also the theorem is about unit-speed reparametrization but your question is about arc-length parametrization.

Comment: I understand that the curve parameterized by arc length is one whose speed is $1$ at all times

Comment: If the curve is not regular, in particular there is time such that $|\gamma'(t)|=0$, then we cannot have unit speed reparametrization, because if $\widetilde{\gamma}(s) = \gamma \circ \varphi(s)$ is unit speed then $\widetilde{\gamma}'(s) = \gamma'(\varphi(s)) \cdot \varphi'(s) = 1$ but this is impossible since $\gamma'(t) = 0$ for some $t$. Another way a curve can be not regular is that the curve is piecewise regular as your example above. If this is the case, we can obtain a unit speed parametrization by joining unit speed parametrization for each regular piece.

Comment: @SiKucing With that I understand what you mean, I thought that the unit-speed and the parameterization by arc length were equivalent. Thank you very much for explaining it.

Comment: Yeah looks like they're the same. Not to hard to prove both ways $\gamma$ unit-speed $\Leftrightarrow$ $\gamma$ parameterize by arc-length.

Comment: @SiKucing: Your remarks aren't quite right. In the piecewise smooth case, you do not have a velocity vector at the corner, and so there is no (everywhere) speed-one parametrization. Moreover, consider the parametrized curve $\alpha(t)=(t^3,t^3)$. This is not regular, but there is a reparametrization by arclength. So be careful.

Comment: @DavidMorante Because your curve has no tangent line at the corner, there can be no regular parametrization.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes. I want to point that out but i thought OP knew that.

Comment: @TedShifrin Didn’t realize about t^3 curve though. I’ll keep that in mind.

Comment: @TedShifrin I would love to see you answer this question for us prof.

Comment: @SiKucing then only when you have a regular curve can I prove $y$unit-speed ⇔ $y$ parameterize by arc-length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have an arclength parametrization, a curve must have a tangent line at each point (since, as you pointed out, an arclength parametrization gives you a length-one velocity vector at each point, and that vector spans the tangent line).

However, if you have a non-regular parametrization whose *image* is still a $1$-dimensional manifold, then that manifold will have a tangent line at each point, even if the parametrization fails to give it. The example I gave in the comments was $\alpha(t) = (t^3,t^3)$, which fails to be regular at $t=0$. Nevertheless, the image of $\alpha$ can obviously be parametrized regularly by $\beta(u)=(u,u)$. The example you gave has no tangent line at the origin and so there can be no arclength parametrization.

It is perhaps not obvious that any connected $1$-dimensional manifold sitting in $\Bbb R^n$ can be parametrized (globally) by arclength. By the implicit function theorem, it can *locally* be parametrized as a graph. You obtain open intervals of the curve which are smoothly parametrized. That's good enough: Write down arclength functions on those open intervals and, since they have to agree (up to a constant, by which we adjust) on the overlaps of those intervals, the arclength function can be defined smoothly on the union of the intervals.